# could not load export data: cannot import error in golanglint

Tags: go, golangci-lint

I see new error in prow job

```
could not load export data: cannot import "github.com/IBM/ibmcloud-volume-interface/lib/utils/reasoncode" (unknown bexport format version -1 ("u\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x00\x1a\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00R\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")), possibly version skew - reinstall package) (typecheck)
171
    utilReasonCode "github.com/IBM/ibmcloud-volume-interface/lib/utils/reasoncode"
172
                   ^
```

https://prow.k8s.io/view/gs/kubernetes-jenkins/pr-logs/pull/kubernetes-sigs_ibm-vpc-block-csi-driver/118/pull-ibm-vpc-block-csi-driver-build/1630562347737157632

Error is unclear and not sure what the fix is.
Has anyone else seen similar issue

Comment: First try updating to the latest release of go and the tools you need to see if it's a bug that has been fixed.

Answer (score -2):

Try cleaning your mod and cache files:

```
go clean --modcache
go mod tidy
go mod download
go mod vendor
```